# How to set bits in registers?

Tags: c, registry, bit, memory-address

There is address of registry (first?) SPI1. 
There is structure with offsets. I suppose it means that 
SPI1_REG_BASE + offset = address of some SPI registry

```
#define SPI1_REG_BASE         (0x01F0E000)
//-----------------------------------------------------
//Register Structure & Defines
//-----------------------------------------------------
typedef struct
{
  volatile uint32_t SPIGCR0;        // 0x0000
  volatile uint32_t SPIGCR1;        // 0x0004
  volatile uint32_t SPIINT;         // 0x0008
  volatile uint32_t SPILVL;         // 0x000C
  volatile uint32_t SPIFLG;         // 0x0010
  volatile uint32_t SPIPC0;         // 0x0014
  volatile uint32_t SPIPC1;         // 0x0018
  volatile uint32_t SPIPC2;         // 0x001C
  volatile uint32_t SPIPC3;         // 0x0020
  volatile uint32_t SPIPC4;         // 0x0024
  volatile uint32_t SPIPC5;         // 0x0028
  volatile uint32_t RSVD0[3];       // 0x002C
  volatile uint32_t SPIDAT0;        // 0x0038
  volatile uint32_t SPIDAT1;        // 0x003C
  volatile uint32_t SPIBUF;         // 0x0040
  volatile uint32_t SPIEMU;         // 0x0044
  volatile uint32_t SPIDELAY;       // 0x0048
  volatile uint32_t SPIDEF;         // 0x004C
  volatile uint32_t SPIFMT0;        // 0x0050
  volatile uint32_t SPIFMT1;        // 0x0054
  volatile uint32_t SPIFMT2;        // 0x0058
  volatile uint32_t SPIFMT3;        // 0x005C
  volatile uint32_t INTVEC0;        // 0x0060
  volatile uint32_t INTVEC1;        // 0x0064
} spi_regs_t;
```

There are some definitions and the definition of pointer  *spi

```
#define CSDEF0 (0x00000001) //bit 0
#define CSHOLD (0x10000000) //bit 28
spi_regs_t *spi = (spi_regs_t *)SPI1_REG_BASE;
```

I misunderstood setting of bits. For example,

```
spi->SPIDEF |= CSDEF0 //set 0 bit in the registry field
```

I understand that SPIDEF - is SPI register which has offset address 4Ch
(0x01F0E000 + 0x4C). But why CSDEF0 is bit 0 ?? There is a field CSDEF in SPIDEF registry (0-7 bits). Is it mean that 7 bit of CSDEF has address 0x00000008 ? and 5 bit has address 0x00000006?

But then why CSHOLD field of SPIDAT1 registry has address 0x10000000 ??

```
spi->SPIDAT1 |= CSHOLD  //set bit 28
```

SPIDAT1 register has offset address 3Ch (0x01F0E000 + 0x3C)
It truly has field CSHOLD (28st bit)

How does |= work in this situation?

I'll be grateful for any help for figuring out... all this %)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**But why CSDEF0 is bit 0 ??**

The purpose of this macro is to set bit-0 to 1. If this macro is ORed with any register, then that register's bit-0 is set to 1.

For example

Lets take `spi->SPIDEF = 0x050A` i.e 0x050A ==> 0000 0101 0000 1010

Now setting 0th bit of spi->SPIDEF using CSDEF0 .

```
0x050A     ==> 0000 0101 0000 1010 
CSDEF0     ==> 0000 0000 0000 0001
               --------------------
```

`spi->SPIDEF ==> 0000 0101 0000 1011`

**why CSHOLD field of SPIDAT1 registry has address 0x10000000??**

Same-way how CSDEF0 is used to represent 0th bit,  CSHOLD  is used for 28th bit.

I guess you confused with Hexa-deciamal and binary representation of 0x000001 and 000001 (???).

```
0x01 is 01. 
0x02 is 10. 
0x100 is 1 0000 0000 
0x1000 is 1 0000 0000 0000 
0x10000000 is 1 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
              ^-- Bit 28 starting from bit-0
```

Comment: Jeyaram, thank you so much for detailed explanation!  CSDEF5 = 0x20 (HEX) it is 0000 0000 0010 0000 (bin) an it represents 5th bit of value in spi->SPIDEF ? Is it correct?

Comment: Correct. you can use that CSDEF5 to set other register's 5th bit to 1 too :)

Answer (score 4):

I think you are misunderstanding the notions of address and value of the registers.

You are right (based on the structure description you gave) when you say that the `CSDEF0` register of the SPI1 module is located at address `0x01F0E000 + 0x4C`. This address will never change, it is defined by the hardware design.

Now with the following statements you are not manipulating addresses but values of the registers:

```
spi->SPIDEF |= CSDEF0; //set 0 bit in the registry field 
spi->SPIDAT1 |= CSHOLD;  //set bit 28
```

The `|=` operator is a bitwise OR and assign operator. It is equivalent to the following :

```
spi->SPIDEF = spi->SPIDEF | CSDEF0; //set 0 bit in the registry field 
spi->SPIDAT1 = spi->SPIDAT1 | CSHOLD;  //set bit 28
```

As `CSDEF0` is defined to `0x00000001`, in the first statement you are effectively setting the LSB bit of the `SPIDEF` register, leaving all other bits to their original value.

Comment: greydet, thank you! spi->SPIDEF |= 0x00000002 will set 1st bit of value which is storing in this registry, because 0x00000002 - is 10 in binary view, so we set 1st bit.

Answer (score 1):

> But why CSDEF0 is bit 0 ?

Because of:

```
#define CSDEF0 (0x00000001) //bit 0
```

What they mean is not a "bit with value 0" but "the bit at position 0".

And concerning the:

> #define CSHOLD (0x10000000) //bit 28

Take a look at converting hex-notation to binary-notation and it will become clear.

> How does |= work in this situation?

The 1-bits **AT** those positions (0 and 28) are *or'ed* into the value that was previously in that variable.

Comment: eznme, Thank you for answer! I converted CSHOLD in HEX. It is 128. I still don't understand how to determine address of bit at position 29?

Comment: There are no *addresses of bits*. To work with bit 29, you use an *integer* which has bit 29 set. This integer is `(1u<<29)`, a.k.a. `0x20000000`. You use `something |= (1u<<29)` to set bit 29, `something &= ~(1u<<29)` to clear bit 29, and `(something & (1u<<29))>>29` to examine bit 29.

Comment: @Myosotis 0x10000000 is b10000000000000000000000000000 the bit at index 28 has value 1.

Comment: @eznme exactly! 0x10000000 is a hex representation, not binary. thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

Bits don't have individual addresses.

Instead a common practise in embedded world is to concatenate several small attributes to a larger register. e.g. one could define some internals of realtime scheduler as:

```
   31 30 29 28 27     26 25 24 32 22     21 20 19     18          0
 [ max_priority  ] [ current_priority] [ reserved]   [  address_xxxx ]
```

Here max_priority would be 5-bit unsigned integer having values 0-31; 
One could as well define max_priority0 being the least significant bit of that value. All these parameters would be accessed within the same absolute address (REG_BASE + offset).